# I'm making an in-browser monochrome LED display. Should I use <canvas> or <div>s to display the LEDs?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm making a monochrome in-browser 'LED' display. It should have a matrix of 33 x 278 'LEDs', each of which is 3 x 3 'real' pixels. It will be used to display a progress bar and current time in HH:MM format, or number of days left in 'NN days' format. It will also be adjustable (the user will be able to set the time).

I see two ways to do this:

1. Use `<canvas>` and draw the 'LEDs' with it.
2. Use a `<div>` for each 'LED'. I feel like I will have more control over each 'LED' with that one, but the thought of almost 10 000 `div`s somewhat scares me.

I'd like to know which of these methods is preferable and why. Or is there another way, perhaps?

Comment: Canvas for sure, in fact have a look at this project.  He created the gameboy and it's display in canvas/js http://imrannazar.com/GameBoy-Emulation-in-JavaScript:-Graphics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10,000 divs *should* scare you.  Each of those, despite only being a tiny pixel, will be stored by the browser with many undefined html attributes as well as internal browser attributes, which all take memory.  Additionally, each div will need to be "flowed" or positioned graphically by the browser, taking computation time.

For pixel-level modifiable graphics, you should use a `canvas`, this is what they are designed and optimized for.

Here is a quick `canvas` demo that draws random 3x3 "pixels" on a canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/feusZ/

It's really not that much code and not too difficult.  Once you have a `setPixel` function, the rest is just implementation of what you want to do with the pixels.

Here is a version with your display size, and which automatically reads the canvas size:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/9jQf4/

There are a number of other ways to do this as well, such as manipulating single pixels, or drawing very short lines.

Comment: "*[...]and will need to be "flowed" graphically*." -- You could just give them absolute position. Though, the performance would probably still be terrible.

Comment: But how would I, using `canvas`, control each individual pixel?

Comment: Your canvas is nothing more than a grid of pixels so the pixel at position 50,50 is either white or black.  Since each real (monitor pixel) is 1/3 of a virtual pixel you'll need to come up with some functions to turn on and off a virtual pixel

Comment: @dstarh is right.  Canvases are basically arrays of modifiable pixels, which is exactly what you want.  And each monitor pixel is 1/9 of a virtual pixel, btw. ;)

Comment: *What*? Could you please provide a link to some reading on this matter?

Comment: in fact you probably want a 2d array that holds your data then write a function that draws from that array to the canvas

Comment: 10,000 DOM elements isn't as bad as you might think. For example, [the largest Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_Civil_War_Generals_(Confederate\)) contains 3,205 `<td>` elements *alone*; that's only a third of the proposed pixel display, and the pixels will be a lot simpler than a lot of flowing text. I encourage *measuring the performance of both*. The canvas will probably be faster, but possibly not by a lot.

Comment: http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/ second result in google for "canvas draw pixel"

Comment: @KevinReid, Fair enough, but in load time alone you will get a significant performance boost, or at least the perception of one, which goes a long way.

Comment: @exizt, I added a quick demo that manipulates 3x3 pixels on a canvas.